How to create and use Resource with calendar by guava?
I'm using Calendar by guava tried to follow the documentation and the demo but couldn't get the result i'm looking for which is showing the appointments of a doctor. I succeeded to show the events without using Resource, but in order to use timeGridWeek  i need to use it.
I have a Model Doctor which can have many Appointments.
I've implemented Resourceable  in Doctor as the following :
public function toResource(): array|Resource
    {
        return Resource::make($this->id)
            ->title(Auth()->user()->full_name);
    }

In Model Appointment i've implemented Eventable as the following :
public function toEvent(): array|Event
    {
        return Event::make(Appointment::find($this->id))
            ->title($this->reference . ' - ' . $this->patient->full_name)
            ->start($this->start_at)
            ->end($this->end_at)
            ->resourceId(auth()->user()->doctor->id)
            ->action('view');
    }

Then in the widget i've defined this :
protected string $calendarView = 'resourceTimeGridWeek';
    protected static bool $isLazy = true;

    public function getEvents(array $fetchInfo = []): Collection|array
    {
        return auth()->user()->doctor->appointments()
            ->with(['patient'])
            ->get()
            ->map(fn ($appointment) => $appointment->toEvent())->all();
    }
    public function getResources(): Collection|array
    {
        return Doctor::query()
            ->where('user_id', auth()->id())
            ->get()
            ->map(fn ($doctor) => [
                'id' => $doctor->id,
                'title' => $doctor->name,
            ])->all();
    }

I don't know why the events are appearing in the calendar.
Thanks for your help.
